# How to find a link with selenium?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium

The question is: How to find a link with Selenium JAVA API in the following scenario:

- The link doesnt have an ID
- There are lot of links, these differ just in the href
- I know some unique information about (substring) the href of the link I want to click on
- All the link have the same text

I wrote this method, I tried to use the xpaths match function:

```
public void clickOnLink(String sub_hrefText){
    String xpath = String.format("a[matches(@href,'%s')]",sub_hrefText);
    browser.findElements(By.xpath(xpath)).get(0).click();
}
```

But I got an exception:

> InvalidSelectorException

Comment: did you try `String.format(".//a[contains(@href, '%s')]", sub_hrefText)`?

Comment: It is super! Works! What was the problem with my version?

Comment: the `.//` at the beginning.  It still needs to be valid XPath :P

Comment: @paul t. You should submit this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say

> I know some unique information about (substring) the href of the link I want to click on

so you can use XPath 1.0 function `contains(haystack, needle)` (see [W3C XPath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains)).

You also need a `//` or -- safer -- `.//` at the beginning of your expression to also select descendant `a` elements of the context node (root node in your case) further down the document tree, and not only direct children `a` nodes.

This gives us:

```
public void clickOnLink(String sub_hrefText){
    String xpath = String.format(".//a[contains(@href, '%s')]",sub_hrefText);
    browser.findElements(By.xpath(xpath)).get(0).click();
}
```